# How do I turn a string into not being a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

If I have an array in js:

```
['{lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777}', '{lat:37.773972, lng:-122.431297}', '{lat:39.916668, lng:116.383331}']
```

How would I make the values not be strings. For example, they should look like this:

```
[{lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777}, {lat:37.773972, lng:-122.431297}, {lat:39.916668, lng:116.383331}]
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Assume it is possible, have a go, and if you run into issues come back with a [mcve]

Comment: I think you're looking for `JSON.parse()`,

Comment: @Mooshua probably not since the input data is not JSON

Comment: Please post what you have already tried so we can help you better.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is expected that you show some effort,  Please see the [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Where did these strings come from? Quite possibly an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those aren't JSON strings you can't parse them.

Use a regex to find the numbers, and then `map` over the array. On each iteration match the numbers, and then return the object making sure you coerce the strings to numbers.

```js
const arr = [
  '{lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777}',
  '{lat:37.773972, lng:-122.431297}',
  '{lat:39.916668, lng:116.383331}'
];

const re = /-?[\d]+\.[\d]+/g;

const out = arr.map(str => {
  const [ lat, lng ] = str.match(re);
  return { lat: +lat, lng: +lng };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you want to parse the strings in your array to Objects. For the strings in your post, they won't be easily converted to an object because they aren't proper JSON. If the initial array is formatted like this instead:

```
['{"lat":52.5159, "lng":13.3777}', '{"lat":37.773972, "lng":-122.431297}', '{"lat":39.916668, "lng":116.383331}']
```

From here we can simply do an array map to get it to Objects from Strings:

```
var input = ['{"lat":52.5159, "lng":13.3777}', '{"lat":37.773972, "lng":-122.431297}', '{"lat":39.916668, "lng":116.383331}']

input = input.map(value => JSON.parse(value));
```

This will make input look like this:

```
[{lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777}, {lat:37.773972, lng:-122.431297}, {lat:39.916668, lng:116.383331}]
```

Comment: The answer by Andy is good if you can't change your input to be valid JSON